# Using R, can I take these monthly targets and split them into daily targets?

Tags: r

I would like to take the following table:
[image: Targets]

and split the data into daily targets, based on the month and the year, so that leap years are taken into consideration using R?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sachin Kidia-Reed! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Hi Sachin. Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is difficult to help you when you include an _image_ of your data, rather than data-as-text that we can copy/paste to test and verify possible solutions. Could you please edit your question to include the actual data? Thanks

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: sorry, guys didnt realise thanks for the effort, been solved below!

@r2evans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `days_in_month` from lubridate to get the correct number of days in each month, including leap years. You can then divide the target by this number.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  summarize(day = seq(days_in_month(
    as.POSIXct(paste(year, match(month, month.name), 1, sep = "-")))),
    .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(daily_target = target_ticket_click / n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-target_ticket_click) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#>         month year day daily_target
#> 1       April 2023   1     278.9667
#> 2       April 2023   2     278.9667
#> 3       April 2023   3     278.9667
#> 4       April 2023   4     278.9667
#> 5       April 2023   5     278.9667
#> 6       April 2023   6     278.9667
#> 7       April 2023   7     278.9667
#> 8       April 2023   8     278.9667
#> 9       April 2023   9     278.9667
#> 10      April 2023  10     278.9667
#> 11      April 2023  11     278.9667
#> 12      April 2023  12     278.9667
#> 13      April 2023  13     278.9667
#> 14      April 2023  14     278.9667
#> 15      April 2023  15     278.9667
#> 16      April 2023  16     278.9667
#> 17      April 2023  17     278.9667
#> 18      April 2023  18     278.9667
#> 19      April 2023  19     278.9667
#> 20      April 2023  20     278.9667
#> 21      April 2023  21     278.9667
#> 22      April 2023  22     278.9667
#> 23      April 2023  23     278.9667
#> 24      April 2023  24     278.9667
#> 25      April 2023  25     278.9667
#> 26      April 2023  26     278.9667
#> 27      April 2023  27     278.9667
#> 28      April 2023  28     278.9667
#> 29      April 2023  29     278.9667
#> 30      April 2023  30     278.9667
#> 31     August 2022   1     256.9677
#> 32     August 2022   2     256.9677
#> 33     August 2022   3     256.9677
#> 34     August 2022   4     256.9677
#> 35     August 2022   5     256.9677
#> 36     August 2022   6     256.9677
#> 37     August 2022   7     256.9677
#> 38     August 2022   8     256.9677
#> 39     August 2022   9     256.9677
#> 40     August 2022  10     256.9677
#> 41     August 2022  11     256.9677
#> 42     August 2022  12     256.9677
#> 43     August 2022  13     256.9677
#> 44     August 2022  14     256.9677
#> 45     August 2022  15     256.9677
#> 46     August 2022  16     256.9677
#> 47     August 2022  17     256.9677
#> 48     August 2022  18     256.9677
#> 49     August 2022  19     256.9677
#> 50     August 2022  20     256.9677
#> 51     August 2022  21     256.9677
#> 52     August 2022  22     256.9677
#> 53     August 2022  23     256.9677
#> 54     August 2022  24     256.9677
#> 55     August 2022  25     256.9677
#> 56     August 2022  26     256.9677
#> 57     August 2022  27     256.9677
#> 58     August 2022  28     256.9677
#> 59     August 2022  29     256.9677
#> 60     August 2022  30     256.9677
#> 61     August 2022  31     256.9677
#> 62   December 2022   1     500.6452
#> 63   December 2022   2     500.6452
#> 64   December 2022   3     500.6452
#> 65   December 2022   4     500.6452
#> 66   December 2022   5     500.6452
#> 67   December 2022   6     500.6452
#> 68   December 2022   7     500.6452
#> 69   December 2022   8     500.6452
#> 70   December 2022   9     500.6452
#> 71   December 2022  10     500.6452
#> 72   December 2022  11     500.6452
#> 73   December 2022  12     500.6452
#> 74   December 2022  13     500.6452
#> 75   December 2022  14     500.6452
#> 76   December 2022  15     500.6452
#> 77   December 2022  16     500.6452
#> 78   December 2022  17     500.6452
#> 79   December 2022  18     500.6452
#> 80   December 2022  19     500.6452
#> 81   December 2022  20     500.6452
#> 82   December 2022  21     500.6452
#> 83   December 2022  22     500.6452
#> 84   December 2022  23     500.6452
#> 85   December 2022  24     500.6452
#> 86   December 2022  25     500.6452
#> 87   December 2022  26     500.6452
#> 88   December 2022  27     500.6452
#> 89   December 2022  28     500.6452
#> 90   December 2022  29     500.6452
#> 91   December 2022  30     500.6452
#> 92   December 2022  31     500.6452
#> 93   February 2023   1     295.3929
#> 94   February 2023   2     295.3929
#> 95   February 2023   3     295.3929
#> 96   February 2023   4     295.3929
#> 97   February 2023   5     295.3929
#> 98   February 2023   6     295.3929
#> 99   February 2023   7     295.3929
#> 100  February 2023   8     295.3929
#> 101  February 2023   9     295.3929
#> 102  February 2023  10     295.3929
#> 103  February 2023  11     295.3929
#> 104  February 2023  12     295.3929
#> 105  February 2023  13     295.3929
#> 106  February 2023  14     295.3929
#> 107  February 2023  15     295.3929
#> 108  February 2023  16     295.3929
#> 109  February 2023  17     295.3929
#> 110  February 2023  18     295.3929
#> 111  February 2023  19     295.3929
#> 112  February 2023  20     295.3929
#> 113  February 2023  21     295.3929
#> 114  February 2023  22     295.3929
#> 115  February 2023  23     295.3929
#> 116  February 2023  24     295.3929
#> 117  February 2023  25     295.3929
#> 118  February 2023  26     295.3929
#> 119  February 2023  27     295.3929
#> 120  February 2023  28     295.3929
#> 121   January 2023   1     265.1613
#> 122   January 2023   2     265.1613
#> 123   January 2023   3     265.1613
#> 124   January 2023   4     265.1613
#> 125   January 2023   5     265.1613
#> 126   January 2023   6     265.1613
#> 127   January 2023   7     265.1613
#> 128   January 2023   8     265.1613
#> 129   January 2023   9     265.1613
#> 130   January 2023  10     265.1613
#> 131   January 2023  11     265.1613
#> 132   January 2023  12     265.1613
#> 133   January 2023  13     265.1613
#> 134   January 2023  14     265.1613
#> 135   January 2023  15     265.1613
#> 136   January 2023  16     265.1613
#> 137   January 2023  17     265.1613
#> 138   January 2023  18     265.1613
#> 139   January 2023  19     265.1613
#> 140   January 2023  20     265.1613
#> 141   January 2023  21     265.1613
#> 142   January 2023  22     265.1613
#> 143   January 2023  23     265.1613
#> 144   January 2023  24     265.1613
#> 145   January 2023  25     265.1613
#> 146   January 2023  26     265.1613
#> 147   January 2023  27     265.1613
#> 148   January 2023  28     265.1613
#> 149   January 2023  29     265.1613
#> 150   January 2023  30     265.1613
#> 151   January 2023  31     265.1613
#> 152      July 2022   1     255.2903
#> 153      July 2022   2     255.2903
#> 154      July 2022   3     255.2903
#> 155      July 2022   4     255.2903
#> 156      July 2022   5     255.2903
#> 157      July 2022   6     255.2903
#> 158      July 2022   7     255.2903
#> 159      July 2022   8     255.2903
#> 160      July 2022   9     255.2903
#> 161      July 2022  10     255.2903
#> 162      July 2022  11     255.2903
#> 163      July 2022  12     255.2903
#> 164      July 2022  13     255.2903
#> 165      July 2022  14     255.2903
#> 166      July 2022  15     255.2903
#> 167      July 2022  16     255.2903
#> 168      July 2022  17     255.2903
#> 169      July 2022  18     255.2903
#> 170      July 2022  19     255.2903
#> 171      July 2022  20     255.2903
#> 172      July 2022  21     255.2903
#> 173      July 2022  22     255.2903
#> 174      July 2022  23     255.2903
#> 175      July 2022  24     255.2903
#> 176      July 2022  25     255.2903
#> 177      July 2022  26     255.2903
#> 178      July 2022  27     255.2903
#> 179      July 2022  28     255.2903
#> 180      July 2022  29     255.2903
#> 181      July 2022  30     255.2903
#> 182      July 2022  31     255.2903
#> 183      June 2022   1     497.7000
#> 184      June 2022   2     497.7000
#> 185      June 2022   3     497.7000
#> 186      June 2022   4     497.7000
#> 187      June 2022   5     497.7000
#> 188      June 2022   6     497.7000
#> 189      June 2022   7     497.7000
#> 190      June 2022   8     497.7000
#> 191      June 2022   9     497.7000
#> 192      June 2022  10     497.7000
#> 193      June 2022  11     497.7000
#> 194      June 2022  12     497.7000
#> 195      June 2022  13     497.7000
#> 196      June 2022  14     497.7000
#> 197      June 2022  15     497.7000
#> 198      June 2022  16     497.7000
#> 199      June 2022  17     497.7000
#> 200      June 2022  18     497.7000
#> 201      June 2022  19     497.7000
#> 202      June 2022  20     497.7000
#> 203      June 2022  21     497.7000
#> 204      June 2022  22     497.7000
#> 205      June 2022  23     497.7000
#> 206      June 2022  24     497.7000
#> 207      June 2022  25     497.7000
#> 208      June 2022  26     497.7000
#> 209      June 2022  27     497.7000
#> 210      June 2022  28     497.7000
#> 211      June 2022  29     497.7000
#> 212      June 2022  30     497.7000
#> 213     March 2023   1     268.3226
#> 214     March 2023   2     268.3226
#> 215     March 2023   3     268.3226
#> 216     March 2023   4     268.3226
#> 217     March 2023   5     268.3226
#> 218     March 2023   6     268.3226
#> 219     March 2023   7     268.3226
#> 220     March 2023   8     268.3226
#> 221     March 2023   9     268.3226
#> 222     March 2023  10     268.3226
#> 223     March 2023  11     268.3226
#> 224     March 2023  12     268.3226
#> 225     March 2023  13     268.3226
#> 226     March 2023  14     268.3226
#> 227     March 2023  15     268.3226
#> 228     March 2023  16     268.3226
#> 229     March 2023  17     268.3226
#> 230     March 2023  18     268.3226
#> 231     March 2023  19     268.3226
#> 232     March 2023  20     268.3226
#> 233     March 2023  21     268.3226
#> 234     March 2023  22     268.3226
#> 235     March 2023  23     268.3226
#> 236     March 2023  24     268.3226
#> 237     March 2023  25     268.3226
#> 238     March 2023  26     268.3226
#> 239     March 2023  27     268.3226
#> 240     March 2023  28     268.3226
#> 241     March 2023  29     268.3226
#> 242     March 2023  30     268.3226
#> 243     March 2023  31     268.3226
#> 244       May 2022   1     478.5161
#> 245       May 2022   2     478.5161
#> 246       May 2022   3     478.5161
#> 247       May 2022   4     478.5161
#> 248       May 2022   5     478.5161
#> 249       May 2022   6     478.5161
#> 250       May 2022   7     478.5161
#> 251       May 2022   8     478.5161
#> 252       May 2022   9     478.5161
#> 253       May 2022  10     478.5161
#> 254       May 2022  11     478.5161
#> 255       May 2022  12     478.5161
#> 256       May 2022  13     478.5161
#> 257       May 2022  14     478.5161
#> 258       May 2022  15     478.5161
#> 259       May 2022  16     478.5161
#> 260       May 2022  17     478.5161
#> 261       May 2022  18     478.5161
#> 262       May 2022  19     478.5161
#> 263       May 2022  20     478.5161
#> 264       May 2022  21     478.5161
#> 265       May 2022  22     478.5161
#> 266       May 2022  23     478.5161
#> 267       May 2022  24     478.5161
#> 268       May 2022  25     478.5161
#> 269       May 2022  26     478.5161
#> 270       May 2022  27     478.5161
#> 271       May 2022  28     478.5161
#> 272       May 2022  29     478.5161
#> 273       May 2022  30     478.5161
#> 274       May 2022  31     478.5161
#> 275  November 2022   1     924.8333
#> 276  November 2022   2     924.8333
#> 277  November 2022   3     924.8333
#> 278  November 2022   4     924.8333
#> 279  November 2022   5     924.8333
#> 280  November 2022   6     924.8333
#> 281  November 2022   7     924.8333
#> 282  November 2022   8     924.8333
#> 283  November 2022   9     924.8333
#> 284  November 2022  10     924.8333
#> 285  November 2022  11     924.8333
#> 286  November 2022  12     924.8333
#> 287  November 2022  13     924.8333
#> 288  November 2022  14     924.8333
#> 289  November 2022  15     924.8333
#> 290  November 2022  16     924.8333
#> 291  November 2022  17     924.8333
#> 292  November 2022  18     924.8333
#> 293  November 2022  19     924.8333
#> 294  November 2022  20     924.8333
#> 295  November 2022  21     924.8333
#> 296  November 2022  22     924.8333
#> 297  November 2022  23     924.8333
#> 298  November 2022  24     924.8333
#> 299  November 2022  25     924.8333
#> 300  November 2022  26     924.8333
#> 301  November 2022  27     924.8333
#> 302  November 2022  28     924.8333
#> 303  November 2022  29     924.8333
#> 304  November 2022  30     924.8333
#> 305   October 2022   1     338.2903
#> 306   October 2022   2     338.2903
#> 307   October 2022   3     338.2903
#> 308   October 2022   4     338.2903
#> 309   October 2022   5     338.2903
#> 310   October 2022   6     338.2903
#> 311   October 2022   7     338.2903
#> 312   October 2022   8     338.2903
#> 313   October 2022   9     338.2903
#> 314   October 2022  10     338.2903
#> 315   October 2022  11     338.2903
#> 316   October 2022  12     338.2903
#> 317   October 2022  13     338.2903
#> 318   October 2022  14     338.2903
#> 319   October 2022  15     338.2903
#> 320   October 2022  16     338.2903
#> 321   October 2022  17     338.2903
#> 322   October 2022  18     338.2903
#> 323   October 2022  19     338.2903
#> 324   October 2022  20     338.2903
#> 325   October 2022  21     338.2903
#> 326   October 2022  22     338.2903
#> 327   October 2022  23     338.2903
#> 328   October 2022  24     338.2903
#> 329   October 2022  25     338.2903
#> 330   October 2022  26     338.2903
#> 331   October 2022  27     338.2903
#> 332   October 2022  28     338.2903
#> 333   October 2022  29     338.2903
#> 334   October 2022  30     338.2903
#> 335   October 2022  31     338.2903
#> 336 September 2022   1     267.2333
#> 337 September 2022   2     267.2333
#> 338 September 2022   3     267.2333
#> 339 September 2022   4     267.2333
#> 340 September 2022   5     267.2333
#> 341 September 2022   6     267.2333
#> 342 September 2022   7     267.2333
#> 343 September 2022   8     267.2333
#> 344 September 2022   9     267.2333
#> 345 September 2022  10     267.2333
#> 346 September 2022  11     267.2333
#> 347 September 2022  12     267.2333
#> 348 September 2022  13     267.2333
#> 349 September 2022  14     267.2333
#> 350 September 2022  15     267.2333
#> 351 September 2022  16     267.2333
#> 352 September 2022  17     267.2333
#> 353 September 2022  18     267.2333
#> 354 September 2022  19     267.2333
#> 355 September 2022  20     267.2333
#> 356 September 2022  21     267.2333
#> 357 September 2022  22     267.2333
#> 358 September 2022  23     267.2333
#> 359 September 2022  24     267.2333
#> 360 September 2022  25     267.2333
#> 361 September 2022  26     267.2333
#> 362 September 2022  27     267.2333
#> 363 September 2022  28     267.2333
#> 364 September 2022  29     267.2333
#> 365 September 2022  30     267.2333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data used - transcribed from image in question**

```r
df <- data.frame(month = c(month.name[5:12], month.name[1:4]),
                 year = c(rep(2022, 8), rep(2023, 4)),
                 target_ticket_click = c(14834, 14931, 7914, 7966, 8017, 10487, 
                                         27745, 15520, 8220, 8271, 8318, 8369))

df
#>        month year target_ticket_click
#> 1        May 2022               14834
#> 2       June 2022               14931
#> 3       July 2022                7914
#> 4     August 2022                7966
#> 5  September 2022                8017
#> 6    October 2022               10487
#> 7   November 2022               27745
#> 8   December 2022               15520
#> 9    January 2023                8220
#> 10  February 2023                8271
#> 11     March 2023                8318
#> 12     April 2023                8369
```

Comment: thanks allan! massively helpful, will make sure to post better quality input data next time!

Comment: Hi Sachin. You need to store the result, i.e.  make the first line `df2 <- df %>%` instead of just `df %>% `. Now `df2` will contain the updated version of your data frame. To write it to Excel, the easiest thing is to write it as a `.csv` file. Something like `write.csv(df2, 'myfile.csv')`. Then you should be able to open it directly in Excel as a csv file.